# Issue while calling routingService to navigate within javascript function

Tags: javascript, angular

I have method that is bound to my angular component called onCellPrepared
I have attached a span tag using jquery within the method, inside the onclick event of the span tag I would like to invoke a angular service to route navigation to another page?

1. How can I call the angular service within my javascript method. Currently it shows error when I call `this.routerService.navigate(...)`
2. Can I route via java script to set where the page should navigate on click of the span area, it should still go via the angular routing config.

   ```
   onCellPrepared(e:any) {
     if (e.cell && e.cell.type == "D") {
       $('<span>')
         .addClass('fa fa-cog')
         .click(function(arg) {
           sessionStorage.setItem("filter",
             JSON.stringify([e.cell.path]));
           this.routerService.navigate(["reconciliation-detail"]);
         })
       .appendTo(e.cellElement);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: can you put that code into backticks

Comment: also jquery is not suggested when using Angular. You can capture events with parenthesis

Comment: Not to confuse you with my last comment but my suggestion would be to capture the click event in the html template like this  (click)="callbackfunction()" and do any validation checks inside the callbackfunction(). Otherwise I provided an answr which may help.

Comment: I am dynamically creating the span tags, as you notice above and attaching the click event to the span element. So is there a way to do this in angular, because I don't have an element to bind to upfront.

Comment: You can use `angular.element` to make a dom element in you're using `1.*`. What Angular JS version are you using?

Comment: Angular version i am using is 4.3.6

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I am pretty sure this is 2+

Comment: megan if your onCellPrepared function is actually getting called then my answer below should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have stems from the context of `this`.

Inside of your click callback function `this` does not refer to your class and does not contain the router service, it refers to the function it is in.

To fix this you can use arrow notation `()=>{}` in place of `function(){}`.

using arrow notation stop a `this` context from being created by the function.

Here is a resource for how to use [Arrow Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: rjustin this works !!!. Thanks for pointing me to arrow notation, i wasnt aware of this until now.

Comment: @megan It is a useful feature but not terribly well known yet.